# How are array types (lists and tuples) and for loops related in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

How are array types (lists and tuples) and for loops related in Python? I am a little bit confused. My English is new.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?  What sort of relational information are you seeking?

Answer (score 2):

Lists:

- They are **mutable**; that is, the elements inside of it are permitted to change.
- They use bracket notation `[]`.

Tuples:

- They are **immutable**; that is, the elements it is comprised of are not permitted to change.
- They use parentheses notation `()`.
- Perform a little faster due to their immutability.

Both lists and tuples:

- Can be **iterated** over (`for x in elements`)
- Can be **sliced** (`elements[1:3]`)
- Can be **indexed** (`elements[0]`)

Comment: Instead of "the elements inside of it are/are not permitted to change", I might say "which elements it is comprised of is/is not permitted to change".  The elements themselves can change if they like.

Answer (score 0):

The general structure of a for loop is:

```
 for some_thing in a_bunch_of_things:
     do_something(some_thing)
```

Lists and tuples can be used in place of `a_bunch_of_things` in my example.  They're not the only thing that can be used there, anything that is *iterable* is allowed.  For each time "through" the loop, the variable `some_thing` will contain the next item in the list, tuple, or iterable.